# Show that either $(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (0,\dots,0)$ is the optimal solution or the LP is unbounded.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

\begin{array}{llclccclcl}
\text{maximize}   & c_1x_1    & + & c_2x_2    & + & \dots & + & c_nx_n \\\text{subject to} & a_{11}x_1 & + & a_{12}x_2 & + & \dots & + & a_{1n}x_n & \le & 0\\                  & a_{21}x_1 & + & a_{22}x_2 & + & \dots & + & a_{2n}x_n & \le & 0\\                  &  & \vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots & & \vdots &  \\                  & a_{m1}x_1 & + & a_{m2}x_2 & + & \dots & + & a_{mn}x_n & \le & 0\\                  &  &  &  &  & x_1, & \dots, & x_n & \ge & 0 \\
\end{array}

Show that either $(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (0,\dots,0)$ is the optimal solution or the LP is unbounded.

Comment: In all the constraints (except the last one), the coefficients $a_{ij} \leq 0$. If $a_{ij} = 0 \forall \ I, j$ then the LP is unbounded.

Comment: @P.J. the coefficients do not need to be negative for the statement to hold

Comment: @LinAlg I was trying to explain the case for $a_{ij} = 0$, certainly not the negative case

Comment: could you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ is not optimal, that means that there is an $x \geq 0$ for which $c^Tx > 0$ and $Ax \leq 0$. Then $\alpha x$ ($\alpha \geq 0$) is also feasible, and by $\alpha \to \infty$ the objective can be made arbitrarily large.